# TOR 3.6, can't put http/https proxy in settings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, network-configuration

With earlier versions I could put proxy in network options, now when I put https proxy there, write address and port, and choose proxy type "http/https", Tor doesn't accept it, it says error, somethin about "can't have two types" or something.

Why's that now?

Comment: How do you add a proxy? Please describe what menus you click. Maybe also a screenshot is helpful here.

Comment: Please post your `torrc` config - it will clarify the issue

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue that will be fixed in the next release caused by the addition of pluggable transport support.  For more information, see [#11658 Unable to set the proxy in TBB 3.6](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11658)  in the Tor Project's bug tracking system.

A short term solution would be to manually edit the "Data/Tor/torrc-defaults" file and comment out all the lines that begin with "ClientTransportPlugin", but you will not be able to use obfs2/obfs3/flashproxy/fte to connect to the Tor network.